# Flutter release APK is different compared to the debug APK when analyzed

Tags: flutter, flutter-build, flutter-release, flutter-apk

In this flutter app i have a java library that uses a json file and a certificate inside the android/app/src/res/raw directory. But when i'am running the app in Release mode it failed to find those json and certificate files. And when i analyze both build APK's, i found out that release APK's res directory is different compared to debug mode. show below.

[This is a screenshot of a release APK when analyzed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eluN5.png)

[This is a screenshot of a debug APK when analyzed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD82E.png)

Is there any way to exclude the res/raw directory from changing? Or to fix it